# How to reload table after create a row in Sequelize with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm creating rows with Sequelize, but I don't know how retrieve this data automactlly.
If I restart the server (and then run sequlize.sync()), this data go back with the updated tables, but I wanna make it automactlly when I make the Create or when I make a request to my API

Comment: What do you mean to retrieve it automatically? After you create a row using sequelize, a row is inserted into the database. Just make a Select (`model.find()` using sequelize) and get the data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I was making the call in my module.js but not inner my get route; now it works perfectly,  thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to Naor Levi for respond (my error was call findAll() outside of the get void), this is the code:

```
api.get('/users',(req, res) => {
User.findAll ({ 
    attributes: ['id', 'name']
}).then(users => {
    return users = users;
}).catch(err => 
    console.log("Error: ", err));
res.json(users);});
```